# Classify each of the following sets as open, closed, or neither

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification

\begin{align*}
& 1) \quad\{x : |x − 5| < 1\} \\
& 2) \quad \{x : (x − 3)^2 ≥ 1\}\\
& 3) \quad \{x : 1 ≤ (x − 4)^2 < 4\}
\end{align*}

my answers I have so far:

$1)$ I solved the inequality and it worked out to be the set $(4,6)$, so I am assuming that this is open.

$2)$ I solved the inequality and it worked out to be $[2,4]$, so I am assuming that this is closed.

$3)$ Not sure how to work this one out given that one side is greater than or equal and the other is just less than.

Comment: "open" and "closed" are not opposites and are not mutually exclusive.  A set can be i) open, ii) closed, iii) both or iv)neither.  So what do you think about no 3) now?  By the way, I really don't like that "assume".  You should be able to rattle off the definition of open set and given a sentence or two explanation about why an "open" interval is an open set via the definition and why a "closed" interval is a closed set via def.  And what the definition of both have to say about an interval that is neither open on one end and close and the other.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that $(1)$ is open and $(2)$ is closed. To work out $(3)$, first work out the inequality $1\leq (x-4)^{2}$ and then work out the inequality $(x-4)^{2}<4$. Since our set satisfies both of these conditions, then you must consider the intersection of the two outcomes you obtained. Finally, recall that intervals of the form $[a,b)$ and $(a,b]$ are neither open or closed.

Comment: okay so i worked out  1 ≤ (x − 4)^2 to be [5,infinity)U(-infinity,3] and (x − 4)^2 < 4 to be (2,6)  so does this mean its neither? (i think my calculations are correct)

Comment: Give a one sentence reason why it isn't open.  (Hint: what is it about the points 5 and 3 that is different than all other points?)  Why isn't it closed?  (hint: what does 2 and 6 which aren't in the set have to do with the set.)

Comment: @mathhelpplease. So the set of $(3)$ is the intersection of those two sets. Is that open or closed?

Comment: so i worked out the intersection to be (2,3)U[5.6)

Comment: @mathhelpplease. Right, but including the point $3$ also. So $(2,3]\cup [5,6)$. Now, do you think this set would be open or closed? Depending on your definition of these two concepts, could you work out an argument that prove your statement? Think first whether either $(2,3]$ or $[5,6)$ are closed or open themselves.

Answer (score 0):

An open set means every point is an interior point.  An interior point is one in which every neighborhood is a subset of the set.

What are the interior points of (1,2)? Is every point an interior point?  (Hint: yes)  Is the set open.

What are the interior points of [1,2]?  Is every point an interior point?  Which ones aren't?  Why not?  Is it open?  What about [1,2)?

A closed set means every limit point of the set is an element of a set.

What are the limit points of (1,2)? of [1, 2)? of [1,2]?  (Hint:  all three of those sets have the same limit points.  Which of the limit points are members of which sets and which limit points are not members of which sets?  Which sets are closed?

Which of (1,2), [1,2] and [1,2) are open? which are closed? which are both? (Hint: none) and which are neither?